# How to align a border using css

Tags: css, html, alignment, border

How do I right-align a border in this code?

This is the CSS code I have:

```css
p {
  text-align: right;
  color: #757575;
  Background-color: #FFFFFF;
  font-size: 2.4em;
  width: 50px;
}
```

```html
<p>Home<br>
  <a href="aboutus.html">About</a><br>
  <a href="gallery.html">gallery</a><br>
  <a href="shop.html">club shop</a><br>
  <a href="theteam.html">The Team</a><br>
  <a href="theteam.html">The Team</a><br>
  <a href="mappractice.html">location</a><br>
  <a href="contactus.html">contact us</a><br>
</p>
```

Comment: What do you mean _right-align a border_? Do you just mean how do you add a border on the right? If so, you need something like `border-right: 1px solid #000;`

Comment: There is no border in your CSS and "aligning a border" is meaningless. What are you actually trying to do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use any of any of the following css class to direct your border in any direction. Hope that is what you are trying to achieve.

.border-right{
border-right: 1px solid black;}

.border-top{
border-top: 1px solid black;}

.border-left{
border-left: 1px solid black;}

.border-bottom{
border-bottom: 1px solid black;}